# How can I sum data from a database table using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, for-loop

In my claim table I have multiple columns. One of these columns is the total claim amount. How can I retrieve this data from the database and find the sum of these totals? I already know how to write a loop to find this sum but not how to retrieve the data from the database and put it in a usable format. Thank you in advance.

```
public ActionResult About()
{
      IQueryable<ClaimsDateGroup> data = from claim in db.Claims
                                         group claim by claim.CreatedDate into dateGroup
                                         select new ClaimsDateGroup();       
      return View();
}
```

Comment: Just a minor comment, tables have columns, not fields...

Comment: Tables have fields too, fields refer single items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just total sum of claims made, use `Sum` (just replace `ClaimsMade` with your actual column name):

```
db.Claims.Sum(c => c.ClaimsMade)
```

Comment: Well, you learn something new everyday. Thanks! One problem though, there seems to be a rounding error and it putting on multiple 0's and then a 7 on the end. Not sure why. Thanks though!

Comment: When you use `float` or `double`, rounding problems might occur. See this article for example: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/. To avoid rounding errors you may switch to `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear what you try to achieve and what technology to use. If you like to use Sql.Linq for this then you need to build aggregation method. Something like

```
Decimal? totalOfClaims = (from claim in db.Claims
                          group claim by claim.CreateDate
                          select claim.CreateDate).Count();
```

You'll get total number of claims for different dates. If this isn't what you after then provide more details in the question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have made it clearer now. I would like to total up all the monetary values being stored in the table.